# Build xml generates error in layout of 3d banner

Tags: android, xml, web

Error in layout:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner

     android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/next"
     android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" >

 </com.start app.android.publish.banner.Banner>

</Relative Layout>
```

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for E:\1-12-13 to 31-12-13\1-12-13\hellobanner\AndroidManifest.xml: The value of attribute "android:value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
[2013-12-03 19:48:19 - hellobanner] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: problem is inside AndroidManifest.xml so please add relevant part of code with question

Comment: post your entire layout xml and your manifest, ensuring the formatting here is readable. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with size of banner...so then banner was not look in layout on Device.....i have test in another phone device code are successfully run

By Default the code of layout is perfect for advertizement of 3d banner .....

Mr Gem_Ram Was wrong for This case........

Now Original Code is Running Properly

Answer (score 0):

Please use this to remove the errors in your XML file. Also create a class as per the message. 
Update your manifest files accordingly and share your error messages then...

To help you further, I've created a class file for you: Banner.Java ===> this will remove the errors

```
public class Banner extends View {

    public Banner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner

     android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/next"
     android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" >

 </com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error now ? Post your layout, manifest in readable format

Comment: U are creating own another class of Banner Class are not need for it .... Mr Gem_Ram

Comment: i think u have not add jar file and sdk of advertisement then u add class of banner.....class are not need for it ..... Any way Thank a lot for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

this banner can Directley open in device without any issue:-

```
 android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/next"
 android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" >
```